# Self-Intersecting Geodesics in Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: homogeneous-spaces, geodesics

A result of Helgason's is that any self-intersecting geodesic in a Riemannian globally symmetric space is simple and closed. To what extent does this generalise to Riemannian naturally reductive homogeneous spaces with the canonical connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every geodesic loop on a compact homogeneous space  is a closed geodesic. Let c be such a loop  c(L)=c(0). Take (n-1) Killing vector fields $X_i$ whose value at p are a basis of $c'(0)^\perp$.  Then $X_i$ restricted to c is a Jacobi field and hence $<X_i(c(t),c'(t)>$ is linear. Since X has bounded length, $<X_i(c(t),c'(t)>=0$
and hence $c'(L)=c'(0)$. I think this may be also true if M is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

For a homogeneous metric there is no reason for a geodesic loop at a point to be necessarily a closed geodesic.  Counterexamples can probably be constructed already using metrics on the 3-sphere constructed by rescaling the round metric along the fiber of the Hopf fibration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Katz. However, what I really want to know is whether every such homogeneous space, which is not symmetric, admits a self-intersecting geodesic.

Comment: No, not every homogeneous space will have a self-intersecting geodesic.  Take for example your favorite simply connected space of nonpositive curvature. You can certainly pick one that's not symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the space must have positive curvature. Are there any examples in this class?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Helgason's result does extend to naturally reductive homogeneous spaces. One reference for this is Wolfang Ziller's paper "Closed geodesics on homogeneous spaces", Math. Z. 152, 1976.